# Why does a one-to-many merge of two data.frames with a lubridate interval variable produce intervals with NA?

Tags: r, lubridate

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(lubridate)

(df1 <- data.frame(id1 = 1:5, id2 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 3)))
#   id1 id2
# 1   1  NA
# 2   2  NA
# 3   3   2
# 4   4   2
# 5   5   3

(df2 <- data.frame(id3 = 2, time = interval(today() - years(1), today())))
#   id3                                             time
# 1   2 2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--2015-11-16 19:00:00 EST

merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = "id2", by.y = "id3", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
#   id2 id1                                             time
# 1   2   3 2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--2015-11-16 19:00:00 EST
# 2   2   4 2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--2015-11-16 19:00:00 EST
# 3   3   5                      2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--NA
# 4  NA   1                      2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--NA
# 5  NA   2                      2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--NA
```

I expected to get:

```
#   id2 id1                                             time
# 1   2   3 2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--2015-11-16 19:00:00 EST
# 2   2   4 2014-11-16 19:00:00 EST--2015-11-16 19:00:00 EST
# 3   3   5                                               NA
# 4  NA   1                                               NA
# 5  NA   2                                               NA
```

So, in this one-to-many merge, `lubridate` created intervals that started at `today() - years(1)` and ended at `NA`, when I would have expected that it would have just created `NA` values.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the `interval` object:

```
str(x <- interval(today() - years(1), today()))
#Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
#  ..@ .Data: num 31536000
#  ..@ start: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2014-11-17 01:00:00"
#  ..@ tzone: chr ""
```

It's an S4 object with three slots and data.table only sets the `.Data` slot to `NA`, similar to this:

```
is.na(x) <- TRUE
str(x)
#Formal class 'Interval' [package "lubridate"] with 3 slots
#  ..@ .Data: num NA
#  ..@ start: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2014-11-17 01:00:00"
#  ..@ tzone: chr ""
```

I'm not sure how data.table could know that you'd want to have the start also be `NA`. Maybe some method for some function could be defined, but I don't know enough about S4 to give more advice.